# Youtube API getRating "none" or "unspecified"

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

I am using getRating to get the user's rating of a YouTube video. According to the docs, the rating can be "dislike", "like", "none", "unspecified". Under what conditions can a rating be unspecified? None is the result before watching a video and after unliking it.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/getRating

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume unspecified would be if the owner disabled ratings for their video. Or maybe if the video is unlisted/private.